# Android Studio wrong check boxes size on emulator with 240x320 resoluton

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Why check boxes are so BIG on 240x320 emulator preview screen? As you can see, other controls are shown well. If launch emulator then all looks good. How to fix it? Use preview is much faster than start an emulator.

[image: Wrong checkbox size]

Comment: These checkboxes are so big, because there are no different resources in SDK. Screens 240*320 are very unusual: `320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).` And in [dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Screens) you can see, that only 5% of devices has ldpi configuration. That's why there are no properly scaled resources in sdk and it shows up so big. In emulator, these images (checkbox = 2 changing images) are scaled down by the system. But this is just preview.

Comment: @Vojtaaa9, I'm sure you are right, I guessed so. Can you suggest how to add those missing resources manually (I scale them by myself)? Where are they located and how named? Can you add the answer, and I'll mark it as solution if it will help. 10x in advance. The efforts needed to add them manually worth the time of launching an emulator. Even just for preview.

Comment: You should find them in your SDK folder. `yourPath\android-sdk\platforms\android-21(targeted SDK)\data\res\drawable-mdpi` you will find a lot more images then in `drawable-ldpi` folder, which points to my first comment. Then, if you scale the images, the name of it should stay the same. But 1st, you shouldn't change the SDK by yourself, it might end up with corrupted files. So make a copy of your project and save it seperatly. 2nd, there is no proof, it will work. All this are just thoughts, based on exprerience, how android works. Also be aware of updating the sdk,it might delete your images.

Comment: @Vojtaaa9, surely it's a not a good idea, 10x. Leave it as it is. But from my eyes it looks like a "bug" in SDK (missing resources for all the possible resolutions). I'm newbie in Android / Android Studio / Java (~2 weeks), so it's confusing for me. I just wanted to take an emulator with lowest resolution possible to check that layout isn't broken.

Comment: There are no resources for this screen size, because today, there are very few devices with this resolution. Because ldpi doesnt necessary mean 240*320 pixel size.